# AG grid with related footer buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am looking at adding footer buttons to my AG Grid and want them to be related to the grid rows i.e. I want them to be either enabled/disabled based on certain row-specific data.

I am not sure if that would require a custom implementation OR if there is some out-of-the-box support within Ag-grid ?

**ISSUE**

```
class CustomPinnedRowRenderer {
  init(params) {
    this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
    this.eGui.innerHTML = `<button id='editBtn'>Edit<button> <button id='deleteBtn' disabled>Delete<button>`;

  }

After executing the line this.eGui.innerHTML, I somehow get an unnecessary/extra button element, NOT sure why...so the actual innerHTML rendered after I inspect is as below;
<button id="editBtn">Edit</button><button> </button><button id="deleteBtn" disabled="">Delete</button><button></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways of achieving this:

- if you have AG Grid enterprise then you could create your own [Custom Status Bar Component](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-status-bar/#example-simple-component)
- if you are using AG Grid community, you could leverage [Pinned Rows](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-pinning/#example-row-pinning) to add an empty row at the top or bottom of the grid, and on that row display a [Custom Cell Renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/) with the controls you require

The key here is the following:

```
<AgGridReact
            // ...
            onRowSelected={(params) => {
              params.api.redrawRows({
                rowNodes: [params.api.getPinnedBottomRow(0)],
              });
            }}
            isFullWidthCell={(rowNode) => rowNode.rowPinned === 'bottom'}
            fullWidthCellRenderer={CustomPinnedRowRenderer}
            pinnedBottomRowData={[{}]}
          ></AgGridReact>
```

- We are adding an empty pinned bottom row by providing an empty object.
- I've also decided to enable [Full Width Rows](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/full-width-rows/) on the pinned row, meaning that the cell renderer component will span the entire width of the grid and not use columns. You can disable this if you wish.
- When a row is selected, we redraw the pinned row to force it to refresh using the grid event `onRowSelected`, so that the logic to disable the button can be recomputed

```
const CustomPinnedRowRenderer = memo((props) => {
  const selectedNodes = props.api.getSelectedNodes();

  const isFirstRowSelected =
    selectedNodes.filter((node) => node.rowIndex === 0).length > 0;
  return (
    <button disabled={isFirstRowSelected}>
      enabled only if first row is selected
    </button>
  );
});
```

See this implemented in the following [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/HGAN7ZI336pLYrBB)

Comment: Thanks...Yes, I am using the AG Grid community...so for the pinned row with custom cell renderer, can I add buttons and then control the state based on row selections above (like say if row 1 is selected, that pinned row button is enabled ?)

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks a lot...Just one last related question/issue. I updated as ISSUE in the initial question..Basically I am using the class variant of CustomPinnedRowRenderer and it seems to be auto-appending an extra element when I am assigning to innerHTML

Comment: You're not closing the `<button>` tags: `<button id='editBtn'>Edit<button>` should be change to `<button id='editBtn'>Edit</button>`